# Best way of achieving multithreading with Azure service bus topics

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core, azureservicebus

I am using Azure service bus with .net core application. I've a topic that process all messages (all tenants).

Here is the code:

```
 private async Task ProcessMessagesAsync<T>(string topiCName, string subscriptionName, Func<List<T>, string, MessageType, Task<bool>> callback, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 {
     var subscriptionExists = await _queueAdmin.SubscriptionExistsAsync(topiCName, subscriptionName);
     if (subscriptionExists)
     {
         using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
         {
             var queue = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IQueue>();

             await queue.ProcessTopicMessagesAsync<T>(topiCName, subscriptionName, callback, cancellationToken);
         }
     }
 }
```

and

```
 public async Task ProcessTopicMessagesAsync<T>(string topicName, string subscriptioName, Func<List<T>, string, MessageType, Task<bool>> callback, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 {
     var receiver = this.CreateTopicReceiver(topicName, subscriptioName, ServiceBusReceiveMode.PeekLock);
     try
     {
         await ProcessTopicMessagesAsync(receiver, _serviceBusConfig.MaxMessagesToProcess, topicName, subscriptioName, cancellationToken, callback);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         _logger.Error($"Error while processing messages from topic {topicName}: {ex}");
         throw;
     }
     finally
     {
         await receiver.DisposeAsync();
     }
 }

private ServiceBusReceiver CreateTopicReceiver(string topicName, string subscriptionName, ServiceBusReceiveMode receiveMode)
{
    return _serviceBusClient.CreateReceiver(topicName, subscriptionName, new ServiceBusReceiverOptions
    {
        ReceiveMode = receiveMode
    });
}
```

I am reading a batch of 200 messages in a single call. This works fine but on production we will have 15000 messages to process. So I was thinking if I should add more threads to process the messages.

Something like:

```
private async Task ProcessMessagesAsync<T>(string topiCName, string subscriptionName, Func<List<T>, string, MessageType, Task<bool>> callback, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 {
     var subscriptionExists = await _queueAdmin.SubscriptionExistsAsync(topiCName, subscriptionName);
     if (subscriptionExists)
     {
         var tasks = new List<Task>();
         using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
         {
             var queue = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IQueue>();
             for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) // 5 threads
             {
                 tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
                 {
                     await queue.ProcessTopicMessagesAsync<T>(topiCName, subscriptionName, callback, cancellationToken);
                 }, cancellationToken));
             }

             await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: _"So I was thinking if I should add more threads to process the messages."_ - What makes you think that? Have you explored your scaling-options?

Comment: Actually we have a VM where we deploy our .net app.

Comment: Does it have 75 Cores? If you need to scale from 200 to 15000 that's what you'd need. At least as a worst-case. I guess 200 is not your absolute max throughput, right? Anyhow - it won't hurt to know the full pallette of scaling options _and consider all of them regarding cost ($$$)_.

Comment: so you're saying i should stick to single thread and increase the batch threshold value?

Comment: No. I am saying: explore what you _can_ do outside of that. _Then_ consider _what_ is applicable to your situation, how it will affect performance and cost, etc.

Comment: ^^  Maybe you'll find that you actually need a combination of different scaling methods? Like, let's say you have 100 tenants, but 2 of them are responsible for 90% traffic. Then it might be beneficial to single them out to their own processor instances and use a combined one for the rest (which maybe could even run on a cheaper plan?) ... (_just as an example_)

Comment: I'd suggest using the ServiceBusProcessor and taking advantage of the MaxConcurrentCalls option.  The processor will manage your concurrency for you.   Start with a value that is 3 times the number of CPU cores in your host and gradually increase if testing shows that throughput is stable.

Comment: Actually I want to process multiple messages in a batch and that's why I am creating receiver rather than a processor and a receiver can't have MaxConcurrentCalls option.